# Словообразование

Tags: словообразование

Правильно ли что слово "Автомотокортеж" пишется слитно?

Answer (score 1):

Правильно: Автомотокортеж

При сочетании двух или нескольких сложных существительных  с одинаковой второй частью, эта вторая часть пишется слитно. Пример: автомотовелогонки. Но: при сочетании с союзом и, при предшествующих словах вместо нее пишется т.н. "висячий дефис". Напр.: газо- и электросварка (вместо газосварка и электросварка).

Comment: _Серж: Напр.: **авто** -, **мото**-и элек**с**тросварка( **вместо гасо**сварка и элек**с**тросварка)._ === Серж, улыбнули!

Comment: Ой, Слава, думал об одном , а писал другое. Спасибо!